# Polkadot block-chain basic concepts

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I am new to block chain,how to understand polka dot block chain ...,please anyone explain me with some example in real time.....

what is substrate
what is dot,why do we use it
how to relate to any use case...

I have tried git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template to set up a node.

Please help me in understanding the same.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

As an overview, there are many aspects that you have to take in consideration when building a blockchain, Polkadot aims to bring robust and accessible solutions to many of them. Please [refer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQ60bTU1bPg) to this video and resources that you can find on [Polkadot Documentation](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/getting-started). After reviewing these documents I hope you understand that the whole ethos of Polkadot is to provide key services and features for other blockchains to be built on top of it and by doing so, they can further focus on their specific application.

Substrate come as an SDK based on rust programming language that provides many useful resources for building blockchains that can for example connect to Polkadot, but this is one of many possible applications and it is not mandatory. Please refer to this [documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/quick-start/substrate-at-a-glance/).

Finally regarding the `substrate-node-template`, you need to take some extra steps if you actually want to become validator, one of them is to actually have a stake in DOT to be eligible, please be extremely mindful about this and I strongly recommend that you first feel confident in the space and the technology before even considering getting into this topic.